# How to make Tkinter checkbuttons work individually and default as checked

Tags: python, function, object, checkbox, tkinter

I am trying to have a series of checkboxes which can be selected or not selected - then when the user presses the button, the letters allocated to the checkboxes should be added to an inputted string and then printed.

I am having 2 major problems;

1. The when the user presses a checkbox, all of the checkboxes are selected.
2. I would like to have the default being that all of them as checked, but I cannot find how to do this. If this cannot be answered, it is less important than the 1st problem, and hence doesn't matter as much.

This is my code so far;

import Tkinter

class MENU():

```
def __init__(self,NewData):
    self.SCREEN = Tkinter.Tk()
    self.NewData = NewData
    self.Selection = {"A":1,"B":1,"C":1,"D":1}     
    self.A = Tkinter.Checkbutton(self.SCREEN,text="A",variable=self.Selection["A"]).pack()
    self.B = Tkinter.Checkbutton(self.SCREEN,text="B",variable=self.Selection["B"]).pack()
    self.C = Tkinter.Checkbutton(self.SCREEN,text="C",variable=self.Selection["C"]).pack()
    self.D = Tkinter.Checkbutton(self.SCREEN,text="D",variable=self.Selection["D"]).pack()

    self.BtnFinish = Tkinter.Button(self.SCREEN,text="Finish selection",command=self.FinishSelection)
    self.BtnFinish.pack()

    self.SCREEN.mainloop()

def FinishSelection(self):
    SelectionString = ""
    for n in self.Selection:
        if self.Selection[n]:
            SelectionString+=n
    self.NewData+="\nQuestions\n"+SelectionString+"\n"
    print self.NewData
```

MENU("")

If it matters at all, this is for Python 2.7.3. Additionally, my thanks, and also apologies to those of you who likely have to point out something incredibly obvious/basic, which, as a beginner for Tkinter, I have not realised.

Answer (score 1):

You must use one of the Tkinter objects `StrintVar`, `IntVar`, `BooleanVar` or `DoubleVar` normally (`StringVar`) as the value of the `variable` argument. You can't use a normal python variable.  You'll have to create an individual variable for each.

For example:

```
self.Selection = {"A": Tkinter.BoolVar(), "B": Tkinter.BoolVar(), ...}
self.Selection["A"].set(True)
...
```

Then, to get the value you'll need to use the `get` method:

```
value = self.Selection["A"].get()
```

Comment: I keep receiving an error saying global variable BoolVar is not defined.

Comment: Since you aren't doing a global import (which is good!) you should do `Tkinter.BoolVar`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I did some messing around and finally figured out how to do it. Cheers for the help